# Menu pushing content to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I’m using a menu on my ASP.Net page with orientation set to horizontal with no sub levels.  It pushes my content all the way to the bottom of the page.  I’ve tried many of the answers for similar issues that I’ve found on SO, but nothing works.  Everyone says to use position:absolute, but this doesn’t work.  I’ve tried every position and placing inside another div, but to no avail.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="wrapper" >
        <div id="Main">
            <div id="MainHeader">

            </div>
            <div id="MainMenu">

            </div>
            <div id="MainContent">
                <asp:Menu ID="nav" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Projects.aspx" Text="Search" Value="Search"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ProjectGeneral.aspx" Text="General Info" Value="General Info"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ProjectSchedule.aspx" Text="Schedule" Value="Schedule"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ProjectNotes.aspx" Text="Notes" Value="Notes"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>

                Project: General Information
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#EADD96">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map" >

    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
outline-style:solid;
outline-color: Black;
outline-width:thin;
}
#Main {
width: 50%;
height: 870px;
/*background: blue;*/
float: left;
}
#MainHeader {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
background: #D8D8D8 ;
}
#MainMenu {
width: 20%;
height: 800px;
background-color:darkgray;
float: left;
}
#MainContent {
background-color:beige;
height: 800px;
margin-left: 20%;
font-family: 'MoolBoran';
font-size:22px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-top:0px;
}
#map {
margin-left: 0%;
height: 870px;
background-color: White;
}
#nav {
position:absolute;
top: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: By having MainContent with position:relative and creating a div outside of the menu with postion:absolute and the menu having position:relative it no longer pushes the content down.

```
<div id="MainContent">
    <div id="NavDiv">
            <asp:Menu ID="nav" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Projects.aspx" Text="Search" Value="Search"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ProjectGeneral.aspx" Text="General Info" Value="General Info"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ProjectSchedule.aspx" Text="Schedule" Value="Schedule"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ProjectNotes.aspx" Text="Notes" Value="Notes"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>

            Project: General Information
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#EADD96">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#MainContent {
    position: relative;
}
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Let me know if the above code works

Comment: I didn't include all of my code in my post which I just added.  I created a test page with just the MainContent, menu, panel and label and your suggestion works, but with my page it does not.